# Select upto a given delimeter across multiple lines

Tags: gvim, macvim

I have a json file and I want to change keys of json file.
For example

```
{
 name: "John",
 age: 31,
 city:"New York",
 school:"xyz"
}
```

I want to make all keys `uppercase`. How can I do this with min keystroke in Vim?

Comment: Min keystroke is not always the most convenient.

Comment: @MaximKim may I know the reason why?

Comment: have a look into vimgolf.com as examples. They do min keystrokes that are rarely convenient.

Comment: I understand it may not be intuitive

Comment: `:%norm! gUt:` does it. Will uppercase everything up to a colon on every line that has one. No effect on lines that don't have a colon in them. Use with a visual selection instead of `%` if you want that on specific lines only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment, min keystrokes are not always the most convenient.

I would go with:

```
:%s/^.*:/\U&/g
```

Or, align all text with vim-easy-align:

```
gaip:
CTRL-V (and select all keys)
U
```

But this has a side effect of all keys aligned with `:`.

Or without a plugin:

1. `/name`
2. `gUiw`
3. `j.j.j.`

Or with normal command:

1. `vap`
2. `:'<,'>norm! wgUiw`

`'<,'>` is inserted automatically

PS, some visuals:
[image]